# How to bind an xml map (xsd) item with attributes to a worksheet cells using Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, xml, vba, xsd

I have a problem with binding the items in a xml map (xsd) to the data in cells. I can do it in all cases except one, when the item has two attributes. I don't know how the path to an attribute  should be defined.

Actually I need to prepare the xml files using given [xsd map](https://www.gov.pl/attachment/4afcac6d-4c7a-491b-bbb6-3da82a2a211b) filled with changing data.

At first I tried to prepare ready form with map loaded and all the items bound to the cells with data. That would be the best choice, but it works fine only until I save and close the file. When I open the file again I have an error message and I have to start over again with loading the map and binding the cells.

So now I have a worksheet with prepared structures for data, but no map and no binding as well. I can easily map all items using "drag and drop" mechanism, but it's a lot of burden, so I prepared the macro which should bind all the map items with prepared structures:

```
         Sub Bind_Data()
         Dim JPKmap As XmlMap
         Dim strXPath As String
         Dim MapTable As ListObject
         Dim MapTableColumn As ListColumn
         Dim r As Range
         Dim n As Integer
        
          ' Specify the schema map to be used
          Set JPKmap = ActiveWorkbook.XmlMaps("JPK_mapa")
          Set r = Range("B3") 'area with cells to be bind
          
          Do While r.Offset(-1) <> "" 'an empty cell ends the area
            ' Specify the element to be mapped
            strXPath = r.Offset(-2) & r.Offset(-1) 'itep path and item name
            ' Debug.Print r.Address & " - " & strXPath
            ' Map the element
            r.XPath.SetValue JPKmap, strXPath
            ' Specify NEXT destination
            Set r = r.Offset(0, 1)
          Loop
        
        ' MapTable (sales)
        Set MapTable = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Tabela1")
        Set r = Range("Tabela1").Cells(1, 1)
        Set r = r.Offset(-1, -1)
        n = 1
        
        Do While r.Offset(0, n) <> ""
          ' Specify the element to be mapped
          strXPath = "/ns1:JPK/ns1:SprzedazWiersz/" & r.Offset(0, n)
          ' Specify destination
          Set MapTableColumn = MapTable.ListColumns(n)
          ' Map the element
          MapTableColumn.XPath.SetValue JPKmap, strXPath
          n = n + 1
        Loop
        
        ' MapTable (purchase)
        Set MapTable = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Tabela2")
        Set r = Range("Tabela2").Cells(1, 1)
        Set r = r.Offset(-1, -1)
        n = 1
        
        Do While r.Offset(0, n) <> ""
          ' Specify the element to be mapped
          strXPath = "/ns1:JPK/ns1:ZakupWiersz/" & r.Offset(0, n)
          ' Specify destination.
          Set MapTableColumn = MapTable.ListColumns(n)
          ' Map the element.
          MapTableColumn.XPath.SetValue JPKmap, strXPath
          n = n + 1
        Loop
        
        End Sub
```

This works fine, except one item. There is an item with two attributes. When I use the "drag and drop" mechanism there is no difference, the attibutes behave like all the other items, but the string made of their path (as seen in the map window) and name of the attribute is invalid when used as a parameter for XPath.SetValue. In the end I have to bind this two attributes (green fields on [the printscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8en0Y.png) ) by hand.

To solve the problem I need one of these:

- a tip how to find the proper XPath string for an attribute
- a tip how to find the XPath of the item which is bound to a given cell (oposite to Sheet.XmlMapQuery(myXpath).Address, which gives address of the cell bound to a given XPath)
- a tip how to save the ready worksheet (with map elements bound to cells) in such a way, that it would open unchanged, without any error

The last one may be tricky, as I did it with other maps, no problem, but not with that one - maybe it is too complicated for Excel?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the answers, and now they look obvious, but on the other hand why nobody answered my (and others - there is more in the net) questions if it so easy?

Back to business:

The answer to the second question: XPath is a property of Range, co you may simply ask in the immediate window to check which item is bound to a cell, say C3:

? Range("C3").XPath

Now the answer to the first question was easy to find, I just the checked XPath of the cell bound to the attribute "kodSystemowy" of iten /ns1:JPK/ns1:Naglowek/ns1:KodFormularza:

/ns1:JPK/ns1:Naglowek/ns1:KodFormularza/@kodSystemowy

As you can see the attribut has a prefix **"@"**.